# 2D graphical interactions in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I want to create small applications in java which I will interact with the graphical elements.  I kind of made this example to explain my question and what kind of interaction that I am mentioning for.

[image: example problem]

Let’s say in this application user will drag ball and drop to the target object (ball will not fall user will drag/drop object up to inside of an target object) whenever user drags the ball inside of the target box;

- color of the box will change and I will have a counter to increase.
- setting will restart itself and target will be more far from
  previous position.

In Stack Over Flow people mentioned lots of different frameworks like;

1. JavaFX
2. Java 2d Graphical libraries (is it convenient to use 2d graphics for this kind of    interactions?)
3. Processing (I think this one is more for visualizing information)
4. Prefuse (Also more about visualizing)
5. Slick2D
6. G
7. Piccolo2d

I am aware this kind of questions are asked in Stack Over but I don’t have too much knowledge about limits of libraries. Therefore, I could not find which one is most suitable for me to learn in order to develop this kinds of applications ? (above it is just an example)

Comment: Go with JavaFX from JDK 8. It's the hottest one!

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting to do things involving key listeners, mouse clicks, GUIs, etc., you want to take a look at the [Swing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

It has pretty much everything you need in order to get this done.

There are of course other solutions, but if you're looking for one that's supported out of the box, it's probably the way to go.

Comment: Good afternoon KepaniHaole;

Thanks for the answer.What I need is represent my objects as graphics,detect which object I am interacting when I click, create rules between objects.(For instance, in this example when user try to drags the ball to the obstacle it should not pass the obstacle etc).

Comment: All of that can be done using Swing. It will require a decent amount of code, but it can definitely be done.

Comment: Good afternoon again;

I am sorry for this question but what do you mean by decent amount of code? Swing is the most efficient way to reach my objectives comparing with other libraries above? Or lets say, using JavaFX is more efficient?

Comment: @CanEldem Never is less or more efficient for achieving the task.  Swing has more history and a greater knowledge base, JavaFX is newer and people are still learning how to take advantage of it.  If you need help, Swing will have a greater community to help you.  If you don't mind figuring things out on your, then FX might be a great opportunity to explorer...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not have to use any of those libraries to do any of that. What you're looking for is a class called `Graphics` it is tied to Swing and is normally used through a paint method.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);
    // do graphical stuff here
    repaint();

}
```

Check out the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/).

For your collision detection, you can use the `Instance` class in my library which is a work in progress. Also found [right here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3s1K0L05bSmRkU3WmhrMXBLcG8/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

Your choice will probably depend a lot on how much experience you have already.  If you want something simple but effective, I'd recommend [Processing](http://processing.org/) for the function you described.

I don't agree that Processing is more for visualization.  In fact, it's a great library for beginners who want to program visual interfaces.  Its 2D implementation is built on the Java 2D Graphics libraries, but it also provides mouse and keyboard interaction (somewhat simplified from what you would get from AWT or Swing, which is only unfortunate if you are already used to one of the others).

If you look at some Processing examples, you'll find that it's very easy to do what you describe.  Here are a couple I found in a brief search that seem related:

- http://processing.org/examples/mousefunctions.html
- http://processing.org/examples/constrain.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nathaniel Jones. I will ask some questions to you, sorry for my ignorance.I am planing to develop a kind of desktop application. I will have some other java classes, considering the example above lets say I will have Statistics class to hold number of drags etc. Is it possible for processing to communicate with java classes on desktop java application? In other words, can I use processing inside of the java application? Another question is it possible to run processing on swing elements? I download processing and it seems it has its own IDE where you run the code.

Comment: Thanks for the questions, @CanEldem. You can run Processing from within its own IDE, or you can use Processing's `core.jar` file from another IDE just as you would any other external jar file. See [here](http://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/) for details. I believe it is possible to use other Java classes from within the Processing IDE, but I tend to use Eclipse. When using Processing, your main class should extend `PApplet`, which is itself an AWT `Applet`, so it integrates well with both AWT and Swing. Your `PApplet` sits inside your `JFrame` next to your other Swing components.